# django-table2 ->how to accomplish getting a multiline cell

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have one column in my table (based on a class, not a model class) that is a python Dict object, I'd like the cells in it's column to display as one line per dict entry.

the class I'm displaying:

```
class MegaDatapoint:

def __init__(self, id=None,
             name=None,
             display_name=None,
             description=None,
             enum_dict=None,

             ):

    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.display_name = display_name
    self.description = description
    self.enum_dict = enum_dict
```

in my tables.py I have the following:

```
class DictColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):

        if type(value) is dict:
            v = ""
            for d in value:
                v += f"{d}->{value[d]}\n\r"
        else:
            v = "--"
        return v


class MegaTable(tables.Table):

    name = tables.Column()
    display_name = tables.Column()
    description = tables.Column()
    enum_dict = DictColumn(attrs={'td': {' white-space':'pre-wrap'} })
```

the template "megadatapoint_table2.html" is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block title %}{{ block.super }}Projects{% endblock %}
{% block container %}
    <div>
        <title>List of Datapoints</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </div>
    <div>
        {% render_table table %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And finally the view:

```
class MegadatapointTableView(SingleTableView):
table_class = MegaDatapointTable
template_name = 'megadatapoint_table2.html'


def get_queryset(self):

    """
    Return the product features for this product
    """
    self.enums = Enumeration.objects.all().order_by('enumeration_group')
    self.enum_values_dict = {}
    for enum in self.enums:

        if enum.enumeration_group.id not in self.enum_values_dict:
            self.enum_values_dict[enum.enumeration_group.id] = {}
        self.enum_values_dict[enum.enumeration_group.id][enum.ordinal] = enum.name
    self.m_dp_list = []

    for dp in Datapoint.objects.all():
        dp_enum_dict = None
        if dp.enumeration_group is not None:
            if dp.enumeration_group.id in self.enum_values:
                dp_enum_dict = self.enum_values_dict[dp.enumeration_group.id]
            else:
                dp_enum = f"opps, no enumeration in DB->{dp.enumeration_group.id}"
        else:
            dp_enum = ""

        mdp = MegaDatapoint(id=dp.id,
                            name=dp.name,
                            display_name=dp.display_name,
                            description=dp.description,
                            enum_dict=dp_enum_dict,

                            )
        self.m_dp_list.append(mdp)

    return self.m_dp_list
```

the column attrs show up in the HTML, but do not render so as to get the multiple lines.

Any clues or help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

found a solution, give up on the custom column, use a "TemplateColumn" with "{{record.enum|linebreaksbr }}" as the template. And in my view, use a string  instead of the dict, with '\n' between the dict entries.

So new enum gen in the view is:

```
    self.enums = Enumeration.objects.all().order_by('enumeration_group','ordinal')
    self.enum_values = {}
    for enum in self.enums:

        if enum.enumeration_group.id in self.enum_values:
            self.enum_values[enum.enumeration_group.id] += f"\n{enum.ordinal}->{enum.name }"
        else:
            self.enum_values[enum.enumeration_group.id] = f"{enum.ordinal}->{enum.name }"
```

And the new table is:

```
class MegaDatapointTable(tables.Table):

   name = tables.Column(linkify=("fele:datapoints_detail", {"pk": tables.A("id")}))
   display_name = tables.Column()
   description = tables.Column()
   enum_group = tables.TemplateColumn("{{record.enum_group|linebreaksbr }}")
```

I think this is a bit cleaner as well....

Answer (score 0):

The first approach should work, but you should use

```
DictColumn(attrs={'td': {'style': 'white-space:pre-wrap;'} })
```

rather than

```
DictColumn(attrs={'td': {'white-space': 'pre-wrap'} })
```